# Chrome extension and javascript break

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on a chrome extension and part of my background.js file, it checks to see if the user has used the option page to login. 
Here is the code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
if( localStorage["mainLogin"] == null){
    alert("Please go to the option page to login");
}
```

I know that `break;` is used in javascript to stop the script. However thats not working on chrome extensions...

Basically, I if this it alert, is should stop and not run the rest of the code.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `break;` is used to go out of a for/while/do loop or switch block.
And what's your 'rest of code'?

Comment: `I know that break; is used in javascript to stop the script.` **False.** If this has worked for you before, then probably it is because `break` breaks your code because it is located somewhere outside a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` does not stop the code from keep going. It is used to "break" out of a loop. (`for/while`) However, `debugger;` can break codes similar to what you want. (This is supported by most of the debugger.)

```
blah();
debugger;  //break point
alert();
```

If you want to stop a function from keep running, do this:

```
(function(){
    alert("a");
    return false;
    alert("b");   //you can't see me
})()
```